# Как вывести из json многомерного сложного массива, нужные объекты?

Tags: php, json

У меня есть код:

```
    $json = file_get_contents('http://moonwalk.cc/api/movies_foreign.json?api_token=d10a8f4368bc3a6e26b11477ad939da1');
    $data = json_decode($json,true);
    foreach ($data["report"]["movies"][0] as $report => $elem1) {
        foreach ($elem1 as $key => $value["kinopoisk_id"]) {
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($value["kinopoisk_id"]);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно вытащить `[kinopoisk_id] => обьекты`! Но я не понимаю пока, документацию перечитал json/php foreach/array. Пока никак.
По каждому я это знаю как сделать, через `for`.

Comment: `var_dump(expression);` делайте, там все просто.

Comment: `[kinopoisk_id] => обьекты!!!` - вы имели в виду "значения"? а то "объекты" - это другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если получить надо только массив id-кинопоиска, то

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://moonwalk.cc/api/movies_foreign.json?api_token=d10a8f4368bc3a6e26b11477ad939da1');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$kpIds = array_column($data['report']['movies'], 'kinopoisk_id');
print_r($kpIds);
```

В массиве будет в т.ч. и `null` значения. Чтобы их убрать можно сделать дополнительно

```
$kpIds = array_filter($kpIds);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как вывести в echo $kpIds?

Comment: @АртурКарволеев `foreach($kpIds as $id){ echo "$id<br/>"; }` или что?

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АртурКарволеев да пожалуйста. Ткните там галку слева от ответа, если решение вам подходит.

Comment: Сделал ради вас!

Comment: @АртурКарволеев ради меня не надо, но так работает сообщество https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer